# BIRT. Average function without value '0'

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I am making reports with BIRT. I have table with "item planed quantity", "finished quantity", and  percentage. Something like this Planed 50 , Finished 20, Percentage 40%... and etc.

and after this line i have sum of 'planed quantity', sum of 'Finished quantity'
and ave of percentage. the main problem is that this ave formula is taking percentage whic is equals to 0.

Anyone know how to set filter or expresion like "measure["percent"] != '0'" or something like this?

Comment: http://192.168.5.197:8080/birt/frameset?__report=report/production_plan_vs_exec.rptdesign
There is my report example, try to put date 2015-07-29 and again 2015-07-29

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to multiple or divide by zero someplace.

Answer (score 0):

for the record, 192.168... is a purely internal IP. Unless someone is on your LAN, they won't have access to it. This means that nobody on the WAN can see the link you posted.

As to your issue - here are a few things to try:
1. Check your data type. I think integers round down so AVE( 12/13 ) will equal 0 instead of 0.923.
2. If your wanting to avoid zero values in your average, you'll need to gather counts of non-zeros which requires some scripting. You'll probably be best off creating a scripted data set for this.

See if you can take a screenshot and attach it to this issue if neither of these ideas work or if you need further assistance (particularly with the second option I suggested).

Thanks!